# prove that the symmetric projection is always orthogonal.

Tags: orthogonality, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices, projection

prove that the symmetric projection is always orthogonal.
answer :
we have: null(A)=ran(At) then A=At so null(A)=ran(A)

Comment: Please include your thoughts about the problem so that the community can (and wants to) assist you.

Comment: i don't have any thoughts man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** In general, we have $\ker(A) = \operatorname{im}(A^T)^\perp$ (ker denotes the kernel/nullspace and im denotes the image/column-space)